# Prevent files from being uploaded after the UiComponent's ajax file upload

Tags: magento2, ajax, forms, uicomponent, file-upload

I'm currently implementing the UiComponent's Form Component, which has a section on using file uploads.

You can define the file upload path and after selecting a file in your form, an AJAX call is being executed where you can process the upload.

However, because this request is "stateless", if you submit your form afterwards, the files selected are still being uploaded.

In other words, You do the same upload of the file twice, once in the ajax call and once on form submit.

Is there a way to notify the Form & let it know we've already uploaded and processed the file?